# Reference a very large pivot table, multiple time, with complex formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I would like to use the data from a big pivot table I created to do more complex computation and pivot tables. I know I can reference a cell within my pivot table using the GETPIVOTDATA function, but my problem is that the pivot table is so big and my formulas so long that they become too large to be read (more than an A4 page in Calibri 11...). Plus, the formulas cannot be expanded to a whole column easily...

I had one idea that could simplify things a lot for me: if I can get a copy of my pivot table which uses regular cells, I can easily work with this regular table and get my analysis done. I know I can copy the values of the table pretty easily, but I would like a copy of my pivot table which LINKS to my pivot table in case I change the data that generate the table. Due to the size of my table, I cannot imagine doing so manually for each cell, is there any way I can do this automatically?

I am also open to any other idea that you can think of.

Comment: You can still reference a pivot table chart by cell address, it just doesn't due it when you click on a cell.  Try typing in the formula =D5 (or some other cell in your pivot table). this formula could be dragged to the size of your pivot table.

Comment: Ho, I did not know that. Thank you very much for your help, it solves my problem!